# Is it possible to change the title of a tab in a tabbed content while using tabber.js?

Tags: javascript

I am using tabber.js script for creating a tabbed content and I would like to change the title of a tab during an onclick event.

I tried setting the title like this,
document.getElementById("mytab1").title = "New Title";

But this does not work.. Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Sorry, I originally interpreted your question as changing the text in the top of a tab, not the title attribute.

As it happens, if you want to change the title attribute the code you are using does in fact work as proven by this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccafF/).

If this code is not working on your website then there are two likely sources for the error...

1. The element ID you are referencing is incorrect.
2. Your code is executing before the DOM has fully loaded (more specifically, before the tab loaded).

If the error is from #1, then you simply have to change the document.getElementById('id') so it matches.

If the error is from #2, then you have two options to fix this using plain JavaScript. Your first option would be to wrap any code that deals with the DOM into a function, and then call that function after the window as fully loaded:

```
window.onload = coolStuff();
function coolStuff() {
    document.getElementById("mytab1").title = "New Title";
}
```

The other option for executing your code is by including your script at the bottom of the `<body>` tag of your html page. This will ensure that the browser has the entire DOM figured out by the time your script is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cool page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mytab1">My cool tab</div>
    <div id="othercoolstuff">Totally cool stuff here</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mytab1 is the ID of the tab and not the title. title is a property of the tab. The tab is defined as follows,
<div class="tabbertab" id="mytab1" title="Old Title">

Comment: @Kdude sorry, totally misread your question. I fixed my answer and I'm sure that I figured out where the error was (I'm betting it was issue#2, calling your code before DOM was ready).

Answer (score 0):

This (untested) function shows the way. Starting at the tab, traverse its siblings toward the parent counting elements with class 'tabbertab' until you reach an element with class 'tabbernav', then the child of that tab with index count is the tab title you want.

```
function changeTabberTitle (tab, newTitle) {
  var idx = 0;
  while (tab) {
    if ((tab = tab.previousSibling) && (tab.className || '').match (/\btabbertab\b/))
      idx++;
    else if ((tab.className || '').match (/\btabbernav\b/)) {
      tab = tab.children[idx];
      tab && (tab.innerHTML = newTitle);
      return !!tab; 
    }
  }  
  return false;
}
```

The function returns true if it succeeds, false otherwise;